# MATLAB - Maximum likelihood for periodic function (angles)

Tags: matlab

In the MATLAB stats tutorials there is a section called *"Fitting a More Complicated Distribution: A Mixture of Two Normals"*
http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/examples/fitting-custom-univariate-distributions.html

```
pdf_normmixture = @(x,p,mu1,mu2,sigma1,sigma2) ...
                     p*normpdf(x,mu1,sigma1) + (1-p)*normpdf(x,mu2,sigma2);
lb = [0 -Inf -Inf 0 0];
ub = [1 Inf Inf Inf Inf];
start = [pStart muStart sigmaStart sigmaStart];
paramEsts = mle(x, 'pdf',pdf_normmixture, 'start',start, 'lower',lb, 'upper',ub)
```

I would like to apply the same methodology for fitting two or more normals to a univariate set of values that I have, but **within a periodic domain**. That is, angles that have values of 0° to 360° linked together as a circular range. I am not sure how to declare it in order to make MATLAB understand this kind of terminology.

Is it possible to change this implementation to add the circular range case?

Regards,
Ignacio

Comment: This is a very interesting problem, and I would be keen to hear some principled ways of doing so. However, there may be better answers on somewhere less programming orientated - e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I will post it there. Should I remove this post from here? Thanks

Comment: No, not unless there is more consensus - I think that similar sort of questions come up here a lot so shouldn't be a problem. There may also be some specifically MATLAB solutions...

Comment: I have implemented a statistical test to compare the cumulative distribution of my data and the fitted function that I have predicted. It is not urgent to answer this question, but if someone wants to be creative any comments are welcomed

Comment: I didn't understand very well your problem. Let n be the size of your entire sample. Are you saying that \sum_{i=1}^{n}theta_i=360? And each theta_i has a normal distribution?

Comment: Each distribution has the same mean and variance? Or are you saying something different?

Comment: Another possibility is that you have n samples of m angles theta_i whose sum_{i=1}^{m}theta_i=360... And any theta_i in each sample has a different mean and variance. By the way, it is not difficult to write it in matlab, but to write it statistically...

Comment: You can't have a normal distribution on a periodic domain, but there are several other distributions you can use. Eg. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrapped_normal_distribution .

To do that in matlab you need to specify the distribution you want to use:
phat = mle(data,'distribution',dist)

Comment: @Daniel it is a wrapped normal distribution.

Comment: @IgnacioIbarraDelRío I never listened anything about this. I am going to take a look!

Comment: @julietKiloRomeo I don't think it is possible to do MLE with your proposed wrapped distribution, with all the k values from -Inf to Inf. However, using several k values to approximate the function properly seems a good idea. Thanks for your answer. –

Answer (score 1):

I am using the von Mises distribution http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mises_distribution which is considered a close approximation to the wrapped normal (see the conditions in Topics in ''circular statistics S. Rao Jammalamadaka, A. SenGupta''). Unfortunately, I do not have the matlab to test it, but I think the code is running. Thus, something like this can be done if the approximation is valid:

**Main function:**

% you should provide the column vector theta 0-2pi

```
n=size(theta,1);

mu=0;

k=1;

theParameters=[mu;k];
options = optimset('TolFun',0.01);
outputPar = fminsearch('ml',theParameters,options,n,theta);
```

**ML function**

```
function mLike=ml(theParameters,n,theta)

mu=theParameters(1,1);
k=theParameters(2,1);

theSum=0;
for i=1:n
   theSum=theSum+k*cos(theta(i,1)-mu);
end    
mLike=-n*log(2*pi*besselj(0,k)) + theSum;
mLike=-mLike;
```

I hope it help! There is also a toolbox in R that deals with this kind of estimation http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/circular/circular.pdf.

If you have problems with the positivity of k, in order to avoid dealing with constrained optimization, do k=exp(kk) and estimate kk instead.

Comment: By the way, if the approximation above is not valid, maybe the data is not wrapped normal!